# Rotating HTML5 canvas strokes input in 3-dimension

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d

I have drawn a list of strokes on a  in HTML5, particularly lines. I intend to make these lines into a 3-dimensional for users to view in 360 degree (at every angle). Of course the angles between these lines are known and are different in 3 dimension space. Is there any javascript library that would allow me to display such a 3D effect (by rotating and spinning those lines and view it at different angle)?

I have found some, but wasn't quite sure if it's applicable to  line. Is there any advice on this? I would like to have my list of lines to be displayed like the cube in "Drag and Drop" section of this page: http://www.arc.id.au/Canvas3DGraphics.html

Appreciate that you share some information with me.

Cheers

Comment: opps, sorry if it irks you :( 
your website is quite cool!! i like that CSS3 3D Box you created! just that I would like to change that 3D cube into something like a 3D lines

Comment: @Derek in fairness he hasn't been provided answers to a few of his questions to actually accept.

Comment: @@ anyway something i found here would be interesting
http://sketchtoy.com/ 
draw and use left and right key to spin the drawings

Comment: @CheeHowWee - If you want to draw 3D objects in canvas, you can use `three.js` to achieve it easily.